# How to get sum of elements by it's position. I have below XML and wanted to get sum of DonneeRensCompl by position using XSLT

Tags: xslt-1.0

I have below code and wanted to get sum of DonneeRensCompl by it's position. Example Position1 = 3.60 (1.30+ 2.30 = 3.60) likewise for all possible positions.

```
    <DATA_DS>
<R>
<Annee>2021</Annee>
<CaseRensCompl>
<CodeRensCompl>235</CodeRensCompl>
<DonneeRensCompl>1.30</DonneeRensCompl>
</CaseRensCompl>
<CaseRensCompl>
<CodeRensCompl>B-1</CodeRensCompl>
<DonneeRensCompl>10650.00</DonneeRensCompl>
</CaseRensCompl>
<CaseRensCompl>
<CodeRensCompl>RZ-RJ</CodeRensCompl>
<DonneeRensCompl>10650.00</DonneeRensCompl>
</CaseRensCompl>
</R>
<R>
<Annee>2021</Annee>
<CaseRensCompl>
<CodeRensCompl>235</CodeRensCompl>
<DonneeRensCompl>2.30</DonneeRensCompl>
</CaseRensCompl>
<CaseRensCompl>
<CodeRensCompl>RZ-CA</CodeRensCompl>
<DonneeRensCompl>10650.00</DonneeRensCompl>
</CaseRensCompl>
</R>
```

</DATA_DS>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't know in advance the number of positions, then you must increment the position in a loop until there are no nodes in the current position:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/DATA_DS">
    <root>
        <xsl:call-template name="sum-by-positions"/>
    </root>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="sum-by-positions">
    <xsl:param name="i" select="1"/>
    <xsl:variable name="cases" select="//CaseRensCompl[$i]" />
    <xsl:if test="$cases">
        <sum position="{$i}">
            <xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum($cases/DonneeRensCompl), '#,##0.00')"/>
        </sum>
        <!-- recursive call -->
        <xsl:call-template name="sum-by-positions">
            <xsl:with-param name="i" select="$i + 1"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to your input example, this will produce:

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <sum position="1">3.60</sum>
   <sum position="2">21,300.00</sum>
   <sum position="3">10,650.00</sum>
</root>
```

To understand how this works, read this note in the [XPath 1.0 specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#path-abbrev):

> **NOTE**: The location path `//para[1]` does not mean the same as the location path `/descendant::para[1]`. The latter selects the first descendant `para` element; the former selects all descendant `para` elements that are the first `para` children of their parents.